# Async callback in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I learn Android and have small problem. Probably I'm able to handle it, but I'd like to know best solution for this kind of issues.

The purpose is to make API call to external service (using Volley), and save result to database (using Room).

I've started with mock of API result and saving it to database. Following good practice I've used separated thread to do that. Later I've added making API request, with RequestQueue and now I have something like that:

```
// HomeActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    importData();
}

private void importData() {
    Thread importData = new Thread(new ImportData());
    importData.start();
    importData.join();
}
```

.

```
// ImportData.java
public class ImportData implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    String url = "http://api.com";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String data = response.toString();

                    List<Data> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
                    // ... formating data ...

                    App.get().getDB().dataDao().insertAll(toAdd);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    App.INSTANCE.getRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

The problem is, after call, in `onResponse` function I'm again in UI thread, so I cannot  use operations on database. Should I create new thread there? If so, I would have to pass response variable into this thread, so I don't think it's good idea. What are other options and which is the best? This is my problem.

Comment: Or you receive the asyncresult inside the onResponse (without the Thread) or you call a sync operation inside your thread, but the second way have the same effect as doing in only one thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for creating a Volley [custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom).

You can create a class that extends Request and do any background stuff you want (like saving to your database) in parseNetworkResponse since this is called from a worker thread.  Then, when the Request is finished, you can do any follow-up UI thread stuff in deliverResponse since that callback is made on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than to create a new thread here, or else you must be able to recieve the network result on a thread other than main thread (Rx-java with retrofit can hep you there) or you can use [RxVolley](https://github.com/kymjs/RxVolley)   if you want to follow along the current code just use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)  pass the data into async task and make database transactions in doInBackground()